# Autohotkey dynamic hotstrings using list of matches

Tags: dynamic, replace, autohotkey

I have the following problem: I have a list of comma separated text values (it's a list of song names and other stuff). Now I want my script to keep track of what I type, as a general hotstring script, and when it matches any of the values, it shall replace the found match with the following: [i]%match%[/i]
The used list is just an example displaying every possibility of general "form" of the names.

```
Songlist = "abc def,ghijk,lmn,, op,qrs (tuvw)"

:?*:%A_Space%::
{
Input, SongName, V*, {Space}.,{Enter}, %Songlist%
if ErrorLevel = Match
{
StringLen,songlength, songname
SendInput {BackSpace %SongLength%}[i]%Songname%[/i]
return
}
}
```

Normally, I can figure things out, but this I just can't get my head around!

Answer (score 0):

I'd always use Arrays instead of a comma seperated list.
Also what you need are dynamic hotstrings and luckily there is a nice library that takes care of this for you:
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/98728-dynamic-hotstrings/
To get the library, create a new ahk script in the folder of your main script, call it Hotstring.ahk and paste+save the code from here into it: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Menixator/ahk-repo/master/Hotstring/Hotstring.ahk
Then try this:

```
#include Hotstring.ahk
match = I Will Replace The Song Names
myList := ["abc def", "ghijk", "lmn", "op", "qrs (tuvw)"] ;create our list as array
Loop % myList.GetGaxIndex() { ;Loop through our array
    Hotstring(myList[A_Index],match) ;replace the song name with the contents of match when it's typed
}
```

If this is not what you were looking for, please be more specific with telling us what you want.
To me it was not clear what you meant by `it shall replace the found match with the following: [i]%match%[/i]`.